# Running an uploaded executable Java program with script

Tags: java, sh

I have a simple .sh script, which runs a Java program:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar Test.jar
```

However, the `Test.jar` is referencing a .jar file in the folder. I would like to know, whether it's possible to execute a file, that has been previously uploaded to a website. *Reason:* The script is sent onto (and then ran from) a server, to which I do not have access, which is why I cannot upload the said .jar file onto it.

I've tried with `wget`, but that command only downloads the file, rather than uses the said file in the script.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
#!/bin/bash
wget http://server/Test.jar
java -jar Test.jar
```